# Too many references candles in dynamic lenght (Pinescript/Tradingview)

Tags: tradingview-api, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to get the lowest when there is a open short trade, and the highest with long trades, both WITHOUT REPAINTING. I call a `ta.barssince` in a int when `strategy.position_size` is < 0 or > 0 and put the variable in lenght of `ta.highest(source, lenght)`. Now, no problem when position size is > 0, script works well without errors, but if the position size is < 0 i get: Pine cannot determine the referencing length of a series. Try using max_bars_back' error. i tried different solutions but i get other correlated errors like: Too many references candles, or: the study references too many candles in history(15649). Hope someone have a solution without changing the nature of the script.

```
tradeshort = strategy.position_size > 0 
tradelong = strategy.position_size < 0
Ll = ta.barssince(tradelong)
Sl = ta.barssince(tradeshort)

extreme = strategy.position_size > 0 ? ta.highest(high, (Ll > 1 ? Ll : 1)) :   strategy.position_size < 0 ? ta.lowest(low, (Sl > 1 ? Sl : 1)) : na
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND!!!

```
strategy(title="strategy", max_bars_back=5000)
```

Comment: Error Loop takes too long to excute (＞500 ms)

Comment: TV have a timeout calculation of 500ms for loop, 20s for full script in free plan and 40s for full script in pro plan, so you have to consider to optimize the loop or reduce it.